# How do I get the power manager settings to stick in Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: monitor

I am unable to utilize the Power Manager Settings (XFCE power manager) that control the monitor to "switch off" after becoming inactive.

I have selected numerous settings between 1 to 10 minutes. I prefer to have the monitor to switch off not sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the XScreenSaver settings to work well. Under the Advanced tab of the application I adjusted the 'display power management' to the time out I wanted. Works just as I want.